# Sending email Attachment via SendGrid c# fails

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I'm working with an Azure mobile services backend and I can send an email successfully via SendGrid. However, each time I try to add an attachment, it fails. I never receive the email. After a little research, I found out that all I needed was a virtual path. I modified the path name but it still does not work.

I can't seem to figure out why this fails.

Below is my code:

```
var client = new SendGridClient("apiKey");

var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress(sender),
            Subject = "Adherence Report",
            PlainTextContent = "Sample Content ",
            HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
        };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(receipient, null));
            msg.AddAttachment(@"~\sample\adherence.csv", "Testing", null, null, null);

        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Comment: _"fails"_ and _"does not work"_ doesn't give us much to go on - do you get any exceptions raised?  Are there any indication of problems within the SendGrid admin interfaces?  Have you inspected the contents of `response`?

Comment: Possible duplicate.  Try the Server.MapPath to get full path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945281/sending-an-email-with-attachment-using-sendgrid

Comment: @JamesThorpe, so far no exceptions are raised and I see no problems within the SendGrid interface. I have printed out the body of the response and this is what I have "response": "System.Net.Http.StreamContent",   "file": "~\\sample\\adherence.txt" }}.

Comment: @PapaBurgundy I made that change as you suggested -     msg.AddAttachment(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\sample\adherence.csv"), "Testing", null, null, null); . I still do not get an email even after this change. If I comment out this line however, I receive the email.

Comment: The status code value I printed out from the response also says it was a BadRequest. "response": "BadRequest",   "file": "~\\sample\\adherence.txt" }}.   I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this case. My code seems correct based on the samples I've seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the contents of the response and realized that is was failing because the scheduled send was being canceled with a `400   BAD REQUEST` error.

After some research, I came across this link [mail errors](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html) from the SendGrid website. Under the section for **Attachment Errors**, they explain that

> The attachment content must be base64 encoded.

This is why my attachment was failing. So to finally get it working, I edited my code as follows:

```
string sampleContent = Base64Encode("Testing");  // base64 encoded string
var client = new SendGridClient("apiKey");

var msg = new SendGridMessage()
    {
        From = new EmailAddress(sender),
        Subject = "Adherence Report",
        PlainTextContent = "Sample Content ",
        HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
    };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(recipient, null));
        msg.AddAttachment("myfile.csv", sampleContent, "text/csv", "attachment", "banner");

    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Turns out this wasn't a duplicate question after all since I was facing a different kind of issue with sending emails via SendGrid. The filename also works just as is. The call to `Server.MapPath` isn't necessary for me.

I'm able to receive emails with attachments successfully.

Comment: For reference, an example of `Base64Encode` could be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743162/459102

Comment: Must be carefull extension of file.If you send pdf document , you must write msg.AddAttachment("myfile.pdf", sampleContent, "text/pdf", "attachment", "banner");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var message = MailHelper.CreateSingleTemplateEmail(fromEmail, toEmail, "yourTemplateId", dictionaryWithVariablesToReplaceOnTemplate);

using var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var attachmentByteArray = webClient.DownloadData(attachmentFileUri);
var attachmentAsStringBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(attachmentByteArray);
message.AddAttachment(attachmentFileName, attachmentAsStringBase64);

await client.SendEmailAsync(message);
```